# mysql select latest timestamp for two matching rows with leftjoin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in MySQL.

The **logs** table has columns: time, user_id, event_type

The **users** table has columns: email, id

Every time a user logs in to the system that generates the logs file, the event_type column value is logged with the value '/dashboard'.

The select statement here will show my *every* time they logged in...

```
SELECT users.email, logs.time 
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN logs ON users.id=logs.user_id 
WHERE logs.event_type LIKE '/dashboard' 
GROUP BY email, time;
```

...but I want to return the result set that shows the email address and timestamp for *only the first time* each user logged in.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `min` for that:

```
SELECT users.email, min(logs.time)
FROM users 
    INNER JOIN logs ON users.id=logs.user_id 
WHERE logs.event_type LIKE '/dashboard' 
GROUP BY email;
```

Also no need for an `outer join` -- you are negating that in your `where` criteria.  If you want to keep the `outer join` and return users that might not have matching records in the `logs` table, then move the criteria to the `on`:

```
SELECT users.email, min(logs.time)
FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN logs ON users.id=logs.user_id 
        AND logs.event_type LIKE '/dashboard' 
GROUP BY email;
```

Comment: Both examples provided in your answer worked like a charm, thanks!  The INNER JOIN one took only 3 seconds to execute, whereas the LEFT JOIN one took 1 min and 28 seconds.  I appreciate the quick assist!